# The following build commands failed: CompileC

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using IONIC framework. But while creating IOS Build, I'm getting this error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC build/abodea.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/abodea.build/Objects-normal/i386/PowerManagement.o abodea/Plugins/at.gofg.sportscomputer.powermanagement/PowerManagement.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/Mehdi/Desktop/Development/project_abode_s 04-02-2016/project_abode_s/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,abodea.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,abodea,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/Mehdi/Desktop/Development/project_abode_s 04-02-2016/project_abode_s/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/Mehdi/Desktop/Development/project_abode_s 04-02-2016/project_abode_s/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

I'm not sure what has happened.
I'm using these commands:

```
cordova platform add ios
cordova build ios
```

Android build is perfectly fine...

Comment: Check your read/write permissions

Comment: read/write permissions for what? and how can I check that?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21997?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

Comment: just remove platform via terminal with command and try to add again then create build it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG... It was just a small problem, which was going to make me mad,,, :(
Today I only upgraded my Cordova version from 5.4.1 to 6.0.0 (latest version) and only this was causing problem... I downgraded my cordova version to 5.4.1 and it fixed for me...

@Beat Thanks for the help...

Comment: Agree, <6.0.0 version build works fine. But iOS App store won't accept <6 versions. So, if you want to deploy into app store, you need to upgrade

Comment: Yes @NagaHemanth, This answer is from 2016. Now you do have to use Cordova 10.0.

Comment: I'm using Cordova 10.0 But still, the issue exists.

Answer (score 1):

just remove platform via terminal with command and try to add again then create build it will work

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, fixed it with creating a new project folder and moving my source files there... Deleting the platform did not suffice.